# Navigate to the specific link is not working according to the database status value in php and sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite

when i clicked the link it does not redirect to the page that specified.i have the sqlite database and there is a database column for status(added,updated like wise).i want to redirect to the page when i clicked the status link in my link.php.Now Object not found error is getting.

this is my link.php code below.

Please can you help me guys.

```
<?php
// Includs database connection
include "db_connect.php";

// Makes query with rowid
$query = "SELECT rowid, * FROM registration";

// Run the query and set query result in $result
// Here $db comes from "db_connection.php"
$result = $db->query($query);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Data List</title>
    <script>
function pop_up(url){
window.open(url,'win2','status=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,width=1076,height=768,directories=no,location=no') 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<br>

<!-- <a href="registration.php">Add New</a>-->
<table>
<tbody>

<tr>
<th style="">status</th>
<th style="">submitted</th>
<th style="">department</th>
<th style="">head</th>
<th style="">title</th>
<th style="">applicant</th>
<th style="">date</th>
</tr>
<?php while($row = $result->fetchArray()) {?>

<!--<tr class="table-row" data-href="update.php?id=<?php echo $row['rowid'];?>" data-target="_blank">-->
<tr>
<td>
<a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $row['rowid'];?>"></a>
</td>
<td><a href="<?php echo $row['rowid'];?>">view</a>
<?php
if ($row['rowid'] == "added"){
    echo "<a href='updated.php" . $row['submitted'] . "updated'>  </a>";

} else {
    echo "<a href='next.php" . $row['submitted'] . "next'>  </a>";
}
?>
</td>
<td><?php echo $row['status'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['submitted'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['department'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['head'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['title'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['applicant'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['date'];?></td>

</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
var tableRows = document.getElementsByClassName('table-row');

for (var i = 0, ln = tableRows.length; i < ln; i++) {
  tableRows[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.open(this.getAttribute('data-href'), this.getAttribute('data-target'));
  });
}

</script>
<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This: `href='updated.php" . $row['submitted'] . "updated'` and `href="<?php echo $row['rowid'];?>"` looks pretty strange. What's the expected output for those lines?

Comment: in this table there are two columns for the submitted.one with link and one without link.the above mentioned line for the link one.if the database row id equals to "added",i want to click the link then navigate to the updated php page loaded with the relavant data that specific to this rowid. if not i want to load the  another page in the else part.                                                        very sorry for the inconvenience                                                                                      i'm newbie to the php.please can you help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You didn't really answer my question though.

Comment: want to display the updated.php page loaded with data that specific to this row id when click this link.very sorry for the inconvenience caused.